# unable to find emails when using to:domain.com

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

This used to work all the time with Outlook 2010 when not using Exchange, but now that I'm on Exchange it does not. Maybe it's not an Exchange issue, but when I want to find all emails sent to a particular company, I do a search using `to:domain.com`. When I do this I get "No results." I know, however, that there are emails to a particular person at this company, but even a search for `to:user@domain.com` produces "No results." If I do a search for `to:LastName`, however, I get results.

For some reason it would appear that Outlook is indexing the first and last names of the recipient, but not the actual email address. Either that or this type of searching doesn't work with Exchange and it's either impossible or there's some other way to do it.

Lastly, and this might be a clue, when I select the Outlook 2010 search bar I get the "Search Tools" tab at the top. In there is a section called "Refine" that offers "From", "Subject", "Has Attachments", etc. Normally these are clickable, but with my Exchange setup they are always greyed out.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior persisted for a day and then, suddenly, Windows 10 decided to re-index everything from scratch. Upon completion, which took a couple days, the problem disappeared: I was able to search normally, as always, and all of the emails were found.

So something in the index must have been corrupted where first and last names of the recipients were indexed, but not their actual email addresses. Or something to that effect. In any event, the behavior was bizarre, but it is resolved now.

If anyone stumbles across this issue in the future, you might want to try to manually rebuild your index.